# c++ share project but hide the core of the code

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to share part of my code with someone so he can add some features to it
but I want to keep the core of the code secret.

The structure of my code is the following (the arrows mean `#include
"header.hpp"`):

```
 ________      ___________ 
|        |    |           |--->|OtherPrivate1.hpp|
|        |--->|Private.hpp|--->|      ...        |\
|        |    |___________|--->|OtherPrivateN.hpp| \
|main.cpp|                                          x-->|SomeOtherPrivate.hpp|
|        |     __________                          /
|        |    |          |---->|OtherShared1.hpp| /
|        |--->|Shared.hpp|---->|      ...       |/
|________|    |__________|---->|OtherSharedM.hpp|
```

The `Private.hpp` contains only one template class called `Private`. The
`Shared.hpp` contains one normal class for which the definition are in
`Shared.cpp`. All other files can contain either one template class or one
normal class. At some point in the inclusion pattern, both part include some
privates files.

I've never created libraries, but from what I understood there is no need to
create a library for template class. Plus as my goal is to hide everything
that is private, having a library and a header file that contains the
definition is not useful.

So I think that using a library is not what I want unless there is a way to
hide the definitions of the template files.

Is there a way to share only some part of my code so the other contributors
can compile, test and run the code but don't have access to other part ?

## Edit

The reason why I want to do that is because I've been developing a code for
two years and now an intern is joining me but I'm not sure that he's going to
stay and I don't want to give him everything.

## ReEdit

The answers are heading toward law, licence, NDA and stuff like that... I'm
happy I learned a bit about this stuff but it was not my initial question. I
don't really have security concern but more readability and simplification. I
don't want to spent 3 months to explain my intern my whole code if he's not
staying...

Comment: Are you naive enough to believe that your secret code is so valuable to want to hide it even from your intern?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It looks like I touched a sensitive question... sorry! I'm worried about the value of my code but my real concern is that the intern is not a coder (I'm not either btw)  and he has no experience with c++. If I give him everything he'll be lost in the code and I might spent a lot of time debugging and explaining him the code. As he will simply add one feature to my code, he doesn't need to have access to everything. I thought that it would be easier for him if he sees the minimum. Then if was possible at the same time to "legally protect" my code, I would be happy too.

Comment: I am a developer (with a PhD in computer science) with 30 years of experience. Believe me, things won't work that way: you need to trust your intern -or any collaborator working on the code-, and you need to explain him your code by showing all of it. Even when you try to make your code modular (in a certain way, it is an impossible dream, GTFW for "leaky abstractions" ...), bugs are whole program things....

Comment: BTW, what kind of application are you coding? What is the approximate code size (in lines of source code)? Do you have written documentation (how much)? You should probably edit your question again to explain more.

Comment: At last, even if your intern just asked *explanations* about your code and did not have time (or skills) to do more, the questions he asked and the explanation you have are worth your time and will improve your own thinking on the software in the future. So hiding some of your code is entirely unproductive (and insulting).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not a developer, neither is my intern. I'm doing a PhD in physics and my code is trying to find the ground state properties of some quantum models. My intern will implement an extension to one of these models. He will not touch the part that solves the model. As it's not my main job, the code is shorter than you thought (12000 lines, which at my level is already a lot) but it's relatively well documented.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should not do that. Either share the full source code, or define and document an API, and give a binary shared library implementing that documented API. If you want others to contribute to your code, give them access to all the source code.

BTW, `template`-s cannot really be hidden.

If you want someone else to contribute to your code, you should give access to your source code.

If you really want to hide things (IMHO it is a bad thing to do, and certainly will repeal potential contributors) you might have some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) infrastructure.

Getting external contributions is always a hard thing. My opinion is that these days making your library [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) is the only way to attract external contributors. Remember that competent developers is a scare resource, why would they contribute to your hidden thing while they have a lots of potential free software projects welcoming external contribution?

At last, a person seeing or having access to your source code does not necessarily have the right to contribute to it or to run your code (in particular, copyright laws separate the ability to read code from the legal permission to compile and run it on a computer). If your are scared of your intern, it is a legal or a social or or relational or a personal issue, not a technical one. (You probably should contact a lawyer for legal aspects and/or a therapist for relational/social/personal aspects, not ask here)

My opinion is that if you want external contributions you should publish your software with a free software license, and if you just want to have an intern (or collaborator) working on your code base you should give him access to the entire source code (you may ask a lawyer to make a written contract about mutual obligations like an [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement), but that is off-topic here). Having someone working on your code and not showing all of it is crazy, inefficient, and insulting. You are likely to ruin your reputation by behaving such way with your intern. If I was your intern, I would be pissed off and won't speak in a good way about you! Trust is even more important than contribution (but is a prerequisite).

A person having seen your source code does not any rights on it, except those defined by law, by license (e.g. a free software license) or by contract.

Details are of course specific to the legal system relevant for your case (so are off-topic here). Ask your lawyer!

### NB

You are probably confusing "abstractions" (a very useful way to design software) and "information hiding" or "secrets"; there are not the same. The point is that bugs appear at the interface or the intersection of abstractions and are usually whole program (e.g. memory leaks, undefined behavior, etc...). Read more about [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction). This is why a developer should access all your source code, not some of it. The alternative would be to have a very well specified and perfectly documented API, and that is very hard to get.

I guess that it is a one person, two years project, so probably less than 150 thousand lines of source code. You probably should not spend 3 months explaining them (and if you do, it means that your software is under-designed and needs strong refactoring, which your intern would help you doing if you explain and show *all* of your source).

Comment: In general I would agree to have something that is free for everyone, but in this particular case I'm not, see my edit.

Comment: If I was your intern, I would run away and find another internship.

Comment: You can (and should) give read access to all of your code (under NDA perhaps) to your intern. That does not make it free software.

Answer (score 1):

If you have template class you are pretty much unable to make these code secret. This is because of the specific of templates that allow you to create the types/methods/functions at the compiling time. When it comes to the other files. I think you have to work on using Factory software design pattern or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If the law of Your country allows it You can ask Your intern to sign a contract that forbids him from disclosing or using anything than He has done or have seen during work with Your code. If He fails to keep a secret then He will need to compensate for every loss that resulted.
This costs You nothing and your intern might do a better job when he sees the whole thing.